# Sql = how to calculate the return vector with a time series of prices?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has columns of `price` and `date`, ordered by the ascending dates. I need to calculate from this a return vector where `return = price ( i) / price ( i- 1)`. The time is not time based, which means that one record can be at 9h34, the next at 9h35, then 9h40 etc...

I have found the following topic:
SQL Syntax for calculating results of returned data
but in Oracle I can't use order by in a subquery, could you please help me?

Comment: Iracema: if an answer 'worked perfectly', go ahead and accept that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle, you could use the `lag` analytic function:

```
select 
     price / (lag(price) over (order by i))
,    ...
from PriceHistory
```

Here, `lag(price) over (order by i)` returns the price of the previous row, in a set ordered by the `i` column.